# Upsert does not add new one when document doesn't exist (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating new docs like this:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
    "counter" : 1,
    "tags" : "red"
}
```

Now I want to update or insert document whether or not it already exists:

```
POST test/_update/2
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.counter += params.count",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "count" : 4
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "counter" : 1
    }
}
```

In my case, `_doc=2` does not exist, for this I added `upsert` into the query so that it will be created automatically when the _doc does not exist.

Instead, I am getting this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_update]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
    "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_update]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Did I misunderstand how it works please?

**UPDATE**

Mapping:

```
PUT /test
{
"mappings": {
  "type_name": {
"properties": {
"counter" : { "type" : "integer" },
"tags": { "type" : "text" }

 }}},
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  }
}
```

ElasticSearch version: "6.8.4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

you were looking at 7.x documentation 
this is the documentation for your version : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-update.html

```
POST test/type_name/2/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.counter += params.count",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "count" : 4
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "counter" : 1
    }
}
```